# Todas as requisições Apache apontando para o mesmo diretório

Tags: php, web-service, apache, aplicação-web, virtualhost

Configurei um VHost para meu projeto da seguinte forma:

1 - adicionei uma linha ao arquivo `/etc/hosts` contendo endereço local, url e alias

```
127.0.0.1 meuprojeto.com meuprojeto
```

2 - Adicionei o arquivo meuprojeto.conf em /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/meuprojeto.conf contendo as seguintes informações:

```
<VirtualHost www.meuprojeto.com>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName wwww.meuprojeto.com
    ServerAlias meuprojeto
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/meuprojeto"
</VirtualHost>
```

Existe uma cópia desse arquivo em `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

Consigo acessar meuprojeto pela url declarada normalmente.

O problema é que agora todas as requisições apontam para a raiz do projeto. Caso em informe o endereço http://localhost a requisição cai no em `/var/www/html/meuprojeto.`

Já verifiquei o diretorio raiz do apache em `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` e ela aponta para:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Agradeço a atenção desde já.

Comment: O Host Pelo Visto está errado, tente colocar assim: `127.0.0.1 meuprojeto.com` e `127.0.0.1 www.meuprojeto.com` embaixo.

Sem Contar que no config lá, está com 4 `wwww`.

Comment: @RaphaelCaldas, acho que foi erro de digitação, hehe. Realizei as alterações sugeridas mas não tive nenhuma mudança. Ai tentei usar a2ensite meuprojeto, de alguma maneira o navegador passou a exibir a index default que existe em localhost ("it, works!"). Mas quando tento acessar outro projeto localhost/projeto2, continua acontecendo o redirecionamento para `/var/www/html/meuprojeto`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oi amigão fui dar uma olhada no meu proprio vHost aqui e peguei ele para lhe mostrar, segue abaixo já adaptado:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName wwww.meuprojeto.com
    ServerAlias meuprojeto.com
    DocumentRoot C:/var/www/html/meuprojeto (não sei como é o seu caminho completo)
</VirtualHost>
```

Boa Sorte, apenas adapte o DocumentRoot ali.

Comment: Estamos quase lá! alterei para `<VirtualHost www.meuprojeto.com:80>` a titulo de teste e funcionou. Porem ainda tem algo errado. Obeserve que quando entro com localhost ele abre a index padrão do apache, se eu informo 127.0.0.1 ele cai na raiz do projeto.

Mas continuo sem conseguir acesso a outros endereços locais...

Comment: Esse erro agora não é mais no vHost, é no Hosts agora, nessa parte eu não sei como te ajudar, infelizmente. Eu uso `xampp` que já me ajuda muito nesse vHost.

Comment: De fato @RaphaelCaldas, o problema é que localhost e meuprojeto, no arquivo hosts, estavamo com o mesmo ip 127.0.0.1. Alterei localhost para 127.0.0.2 e deu tudo certo. Obrigado pela atenção! Abraço.